# How to find detailed duplicated records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, duplicates

I need to retrieve all information about records that are duplicates for specific fields.

If I would use mysql I could solve in this way:

```
drop table if exists test;

create table test (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
surname varchar(50),
firstname varchar(50),
sex char(1),
dob date,
pob varchar(50),
otherfield1 varchar(50),
otherfield2 varchar(50)
) engine = myisam;


insert into test (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob,otherfield1,otherfield2)
values 
('smith','john','M','2000-01-01','rome','xxx','yyy'),
('black','jack','M','1990-12-30','milan','aaaaa','vvvv'),
('smith','john','M','2000-01-01','rome','zzz','aaaaa'),
('white','mike','M','1980-03-01','naples','zzz','other text'),
('white','mike','M','1980-03-01','naples','zzz','foo bar'),
('smith','ann','F','1992-03-05','turin','aaaaaaa','other text');


select * from test where (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob) in (
select 
surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob
from test
group by surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob
having count(*) > 1
)
```

and I'll get

```
"id"    "surname"   "firstname" "sex"   "dob"            "pob"  "otherfield1"   "otherfield2"
"1" "smith"           "john"    "M" "2000-01-01"    "rome"     "xxx"    "yyy"
"3" "smith"           "john"    "M" "2000-01-01"    "rome"     "zzz"    "aaaaa"
"4" "white"           "mike"    "M" "1980-03-01"    "naples"   "zzz"    "other text"
"5" "white"           "mike"    "M" "1980-03-01"    "naples"   "zzz"    "foo bar"
```

However this method doesn't work with mssql 2005:

```
create table #test (
id int identity,
surname varchar(50),
firstname varchar(50),
sex char(1),
dob datetime,
pob varchar(50),
otherfield1 varchar(50),
otherfield2 varchar(50)
)

insert into #test (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob,otherfield1,otherfield2) values ('smith','john','M','2000-01-01','rome','xxx','yyy');
insert into #test (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob,otherfield1,otherfield2) values ('black','jack','M','1990-12-30','milan','aaaaa','vvvv');
insert into #test (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob,otherfield1,otherfield2) values ('smith','john','M','2000-01-01','rome','zzz','aaaaa');
insert into #test (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob,otherfield1,otherfield2) values ('white','mike','M','1980-03-01','naples','zzz','other text');
insert into #test (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob,otherfield1,otherfield2) values ('white','mike','M','1980-03-01','naples','zzz','foo bar');
insert into #test (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob,otherfield1,otherfield2) values ('smith','ann','F','1992-03-05','turin','aaaaaaa','other text');

select * from #test where (surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob) in (
select 
surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob
from #test
group by surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob
having count(*) > 1
)
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is a possible solution I've found:

```
select t1.* from #test as t1
inner join (select 
            surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob
            from #test
            group by surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob
            having count(*) > 1) as t2
on t1.surname = t2.surname and t1.firstname = t2.firstname and t1.sex = t2.sex and t1.dob = t2.dob and t1.pob = t2.pob
```

but I'd like to know if there is a better way. I don't like to join all these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * /*TODO: Just list desired columns*/
FROM   (SELECT *,
                Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob) AS Cnt
        FROM   #test) T
WHERE  Cnt > 1
```

-Or

```
SELECT *
FROM   #test t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   #test t2
               WHERE  t1.id <> t2.id
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT t1.surname,
                                         t1.firstname,
                                         t1.sex,
                                         t1.dob,
                                         t1.pob
                                  INTERSECT
                                  SELECT t2.surname,
                                         t2.firstname,
                                         t2.sex,
                                         t2.dob,
                                         t2.pob))
```

Comment: Hi Martin and thanks for your kindness. I've tested both your solutions. My table has 1,5 million of records. First query takes about 10 minutes to find 14 thousands records. Second query takes 90 seconds to give me the same recordset. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob from 
(
select  
surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob, count(*) as NumberOfRecords
from #test 
group by surname,firstname,sex,dob,pob 
) dupCount
Where dupCount.NumberOfRecords > 1
```

This should work in 2005

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply but I need to retrieve all the fields, event otherfield1 and otherfield2 in my simplified example. Take a look at my desired output that I get using mysql.